# Can This Argument Get Represented in Predicate Logic?

Tags: geometry, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Reading a paper entitled [Predication in the Logic of Terms](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1093635336) on p. 114 Fred Sommers made a simple argument as follows:

"June smiles at someone.  Therefore, June smiles."

Sommers said that this argument cannot get proven in modern predicate logic, but shows how it can get proven in his system.

I don't recall how existential elimination works exactly, but do recall that the subtleties take a lot of carefulness to keep straight, so I'm not sure his claim correct.

Consider the following argument:

"Some cubic object contains something.  Therefore, some cubic object is a container (or perhaps 'some cubic object contains.'"

I think that in term-functor logic (with a prefix scheme) that could proved as follows, letting C stand for a cube, I for a container, and S for something (the indexing matters here):

```
assumption              1. + C1 + I12 S2
by association, 1.      2. + + C1 I12 S2
by + simplification, 2. 3. + C1 I12
```

Can the above argument which concludes that some cubic object (or make it a nice and tidy cube, I suppose) is a container get proved in modern predicate calculus?

Comment: The issue is that in predicate logic (without some addiotional specific "axioms" for the "theory of smiling") we cannot link the binary predicate $Smile.at(June, y)$ with the unary predicate $Smiles(x)$...

Comment: We need a sort of axiom : $\forall x \ [ \exists y \ Smile.at(x,y) \to Smiles(x)]$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA From what I've read recently, the Fregean theory originally would interpret something like Smiles.at(x) and Smiles.at(x, y) as functions to the The True or The False.  So, might something like currying work to solve this sort of problem?